# Почему root.attributes('-topmost', False) срабатывает через раз?

Tags: python, tkinter, win32gui

Пытаюсь организовать привязку панели к приложению.
Нужно, чтобы при активном окне программы панель была активна и поверх всех окон, а при неактивном окне программы панель была неактивна и не поверх всех окон.

возникла проблема, команда `root.attributes('-topmost', False)` срабатывает через раз (при перещелкивании между окнами программы и сторонних програм, при перетаскивании программы.), как исправить этот баг?

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui

# Константы
NAME = 'КОМПАС-3D'
W = 28
H = 100
IX = 147
IY = 2

# Переменные
topmost = True
old_kp = kp = np = [-32000, -32000, -30000, -30000]
old_hwnd = new_hwnd = 0
old_name = new_name = '223'

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.lift()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='#F2F2F2', highlightthickness=1,
               highlightbackground='#666666', highlightcolor='#666666')


def update_topmost():
    global NAME, topmost, new_name
    if NAME not in new_name:
        topmost = False
    elif NAME in new_name:
        topmost = True
    else:
        topmost = False
    root.attributes('-topmost', topmost)


def update_geometry():
    global NAME, W, H, IX, IY, kp, old_hwnd, old_name, new_name, new_hwnd
    if NAME in new_name:
        kp = win32gui.GetWindowRect(new_hwnd)
        old_hwnd = new_hwnd
        old_name = new_name
    elif NAME not in new_name and NAME in old_name:
        kp = win32gui.GetWindowRect(old_hwnd)
    else:
        kp = np
    root.geometry(f'{W}x{H}+{kp[2]-W-IY}+{kp[1]+IX}')


def update_position():
    global kp, old_kp, new_name, new_hwnd
    while True:
        new_hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        new_name = win32gui.GetWindowText(new_hwnd)
        old_kp = kp

        update_topmost()
        update_geometry()
        root.update()

update_position()
root.mainloop()
```

### немного исправил ситуацию,
 но полностью проблему это не решило:

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import time

# Константы
KNAME = 'КОМПАС-3D v'
W = 28
H = 100
IX = 147
IY = 2

# Переменные
topmost = True
kp = np = [-32000, -32000, -30000, -30000]
old_hwnd = old_k_hwnd = 0
old_name = ''

root = tk.Tk()
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg='#F2F2F2', highlightthickness=1,
               highlightbackground='#666666', highlightcolor='#666666')
root.geometry(f'{W}x{H}')


def set_topmost(_value):
    root.attributes('-topmost', _value)
    return


def get_window_rect(_hwnd):
    try:
        return win32gui.GetWindowRect(_hwnd)
    except Exception:
        return np


def update_position():
    global hwnd, name, kp, old_kp, old_hwnd, old_name, old_k_hwnd
    while True:
        hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        name = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        old_kp = kp

        if KNAME not in name or hwnd == 0:
            set_topmost(False)
            time.sleep(0.015)
            set_topmost(False)
        elif KNAME in name and hwnd != 0:
            set_topmost(True)

        if KNAME in name:
            old_k_hwnd = hwnd
            kp = get_window_rect(hwnd)
        else:
            kp = get_window_rect(old_k_hwnd)

        old_name = name
        old_hwnd = hwnd


        root.geometry(f'+{kp[2]-W-IY}+{kp[1]+IX}')
        root.update()



update_position()
root.mainloop()
```

И еще:
значение `-topmost` меняется, но окно остается по-прежнему сверху (иногда)
Компас - Проводник (~1 раз из 30)
Компас - Atom (~5 раз из 30)

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: мысль какая, поставил таймер 0,5 сек. после обновления, получается такая штука: при переводе на окно компаса происходит обновление виджета, но при переходе на стороннее не обновлятся, при переходе со стороннего на другое стороннее обновляется, у меня есть параметры `old_`, и при переводе на сторонне окно позиция окна не меняется. Видимо `update()` срабатывает только если параметры `geometry()` изменились, а при изменении атрибута `attributes('-topmost'` `update` не срабатывает.

Comment: Замена команды `root.attributes('-topmost', topmost)` на `root.after_idle(root.call, 'wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', topmost)` ничего не дает

Comment: Есть еще у кого идеи как избавиться от проблемы?